# NVMe partitions, dev/loop partitions?

Tags: partitioning, nvme

I'm using an NVMe drive, but I don't understand what all these dev/loops- partitions are. Should I do something about it, or is this perfectly normal?

```
    df -h
Filsystem      Størrelse Brukt Tilgj. Bruk% Montert på
udev                3,9G     0   3,9G    0% /dev
tmpfs               786M  3,4M   782M    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6       78G   26G    49G   35% /
tmpfs               3,9G   43M   3,8G    2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5,0M  4,0K   5,0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs               3,9G     0   3,9G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0          140M  140M      0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
/dev/loop1           22M   22M      0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/31
/dev/loop3          6,0M  6,0M      0  100% /snap/communitheme/246
/dev/loop2           13M   13M      0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/69
/dev/loop6           28M   28M      0  100% /snap/ohmygiraffe/3
/dev/loop5          163M  163M      0  100% /snap/spotify/13
/dev/loop8          141M  141M      0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/62
/dev/loop7           13M   13M      0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/86
/dev/loop9           87M   87M      0  100% /snap/core/4571
/dev/loop12          87M   87M      0  100% /snap/core/4650
/dev/loop10          94M   94M      0  100% /snap/slack/6
/dev/loop11         6,0M  6,0M      0  100% /snap/communitheme/285
/dev/loop13         141M  141M      0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
/dev/loop15         221M  221M      0  100% /snap/pycharm-educational/6
/dev/loop14          21M   21M      0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/25
/dev/loop16         2,4M  2,4M      0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/167
/dev/loop17         129M  129M      0  100% /snap/auryo/13
/dev/loop18         1,7M  1,7M      0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/154
/dev/loop19          87M   87M      0  100% /snap/core/4486
/dev/nvme0n1p1      256M   32M   225M   13% /boot/efi
tmpfs               786M   16K   786M    1% /run/user/120
tmpfs               786M   72K   786M    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop20         6,0M  6,0M      0  100% /snap/communitheme/306
/dev/loop4          218M  218M      0  100% /snap/pycharm-educational/7
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text and post text as text and format it accordingly.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the text you want to show, instead of posting an image of a window of a program with that text inside.

Comment: Sorry, will do this in my next questions.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please do not change the title of your questions to include word's like `[Solved]`, mark the answers which where useful for you as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside them. Thank you.

Comment: Suggest taking `NVMe` out of the title because it has nothing to do with the `snap` loop devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are from [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) packages. You have several of your packages installed using `snap` (which happens by default in ubuntu 18.04). This is normal and aside from removing those packages and installing them without snap you can't (or at least shouldn't) do anything against them.

**Update**: To clarify in regard to your question in comment, these are not exactly partitions but files that contain a filesystem inside and that are mounted to the respective location. That way the package creator can package up a whole application in a single file but the OS using the application can access all the files as it normally would. The concept used here are so called `loop` mounts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Maybe I should check out how snaps work because I find it a bit strange how it would create a partition for a program. Maybe its a way of virtualization?
Will do some research now, but thanks again

Comment: Huh, clever
Well, ok - I will let them be :)